# IntelliJ debugger doesn't work with Dojo require

Tags: javascript, dojo, intellij-idea

I'm having problem with JavaScript debugger under project that uses `dojo.require()` to load JavaScript files.

Under debugger I can see only files loaded using standard `<script/>` tag. Also I cannot see any debugger "frame".

Setup:

- Mac
- Intellij 10.5
- Fx 10 with Intellij extension

Above setup works fine under other projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an open bug for this:

- [IDEA-63523](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-63523) Can't debug Dojo Widgets

Comment: Hmm, the same problem is under Chrome.. Do you know when it will be fixed?

Comment: Does it affect IntelliJ 11 as well?

Comment: The issue is still open, so it most likely affects IDEA 11 as well.